# unable to get the username if the data is entered from the front end in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am creating an invoice app, I want once the data is entered the app should automatically pick the user. if I am entering the data from admin panel it works fine.. but when I enter the data using forms in front end it takes the user name as 'none' only.

Comment: Can you post your code to get a clear idea of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.